# How to set an imageview with a picture from firebase storage

Tags: firebase, imageview, firebase-storage

I am trying to retrieve images manually uploaded from firebase storage and display them in image vies in the app. I tried this method below. The reason I used the code below is because in future i would like to change the images by simply deleting the image on the database and replacing it with a new image under the same name as the previous. e.g an image of a tree named 'A' in my firebase is deleted and replaced with an image of a dog named 'A'

```
private FirebaseStorage storage=FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
private ImageView mIm;
private StorageReference
```

.....

```
mIm=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewtiko);
    final long ONE_MEGABYTE=1024*1024;
    storageRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length);
            mIm.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    });
```

The app does not crash nor is there an error message when running, but it simply does not display the image. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply added an onFailureListener and it worked fine